# Interpreting Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) Plot: Rotation and Axis Orientation

Tags: interpretation, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling

First post here, so let me know if I'm missing things. I'm working with a multidimensional scaling (MDS) plot generated in MATLAB using cmdscale(1-(corr(Betas))). Based on prior experiments, I suspect two of the axes in the data closely align with my expected X and Y axes. However, the plot doesn't automatically orient them this way. I know that this means that the axes chosen by the MDS are the ones that explain variance, but the previous axes are visibly present except the plot is rotated ~45 degrees.

My question is: Is it appropriate to rotate or flip the MDS plot to align the axes with the top sources of variance I've seen in previous work?

Here's some additional context:

The data matrix used for cmdscale is named Betas.
I'm calculating pairwise correlations using corr(Betas).
The resulting MDS plot seems to have two dominant axes that do not visually align with my expected X and Y directions which are born from the experimental design.
I understand that rotating or flipping the plot might alter the interpretation of the plot, but the distances between points would be preserved. However, I'm primarily interested in identifying the axes that capture the most variance and aligning them visually for easier interpretation.

Is there a recommended approach for achieving this alignment in MATLAB while preserving the underlying relationships in the data? Is it appropriate to simply rotate the plot 45 degrees and describe the new axes?

As a bonus follow-up, if only the relationship between points is important for description, and the orientation of the overall plot is not essential, would there be a method to most aptly align the plot to maximize the previously seen axes? In other words, is there a way to find the more accurate degree of rotation in the new, rotated plot?

Any insights or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
McKinney Pitts

Comment: In what way would rotating or flipping the plot affect its interpretation?

Comment: You can rotate the mds axes as you like if your mds analysis was single-matrix one, i.e. not INDSCAL model or such.

Comment: I'm concerned that, while the axes are semi-arbitrary in the sense that they aren't specified beforehand, it might be disingenuous to show it rotated since it displays my new, rotated axes as the axes along which the data varies

Comment: Any thoughts regrading the "bonus follow-up" then? The plan I had was to use one of the axes that the MDS bore out as a continuous variable on an x-axis to then plot other data against. However, I worry that any rotation I perform (if not done in some systematic way to maximize the extent of the new rotated, axis) would be subject to my own whims and choices of degree-of-rotation.